# Exception "objectForKey unrecognized selector" when parsing JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

Hi I am very new for ios and in my project I am using web services in my app.

And here for services I am maintaining separate Background class and getting response using "protocols". Ok that's fine. I am getting response from services well.

But my problem is here sometimes it's showing an exception like "objectForKey unrecognized selector send" and some times it's loading fine why this problem is coming see my below code.

And if there is no data it's showing like alert no data available in that way I have maintain if and else conditions but why this problem is coming?

### BackgroundServiceClass:-

```
#import "BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass.h"

@interface BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass ()

@end

@implementation BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)getServieCalling :(NSString*)mainurl{


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mainurl]

                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy

                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil) {

            NSLog(@"fundamental network error = %@", error);

            return;
        }

        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

            NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
            if (statusCode != 200) {

                NSLog(@"Warning; server should respond with 200 status code, but returned %ld", (long)statusCode);
            }
        }

        NSError *parseError;
        NSMutableArray *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

        if (responseObject) {


             [self MainService:responseObject];

        }

        else {

            NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", parseError);

            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"responseString = %@", responseString);
        }
    }];

    [task resume];
}

-(void)MainService :(NSMutableArray*) mainArrayList{

    [delegate GetCallService : mainArrayList];
}

@end
```

### my mainClass:-

```
@interface Mainclass ()
{
 BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass * Get;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [Get getServieCalling:@"my url here"];

}
- (void) GetCallService: (NSMutableArray*)mainArrayList{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    NameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    IdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (mainArrayList.count<1) {

            NSLog(@"No data available");

      }else{

      for (NSDictionary * obj in mainArrayList) {

        NSString * Name = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSString * Id = [obj objectForKey:@"id"];
        [NameArray addObject:Name];
        [IdArray addObject:Id];
      }

     NSLog(@"final NameArray is %@",NameArray);
     NSLog(@"final IdArray is %@",IdArray);

       });
 }
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the delegate of the BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass object? also I don't see the place where you create an object of BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to change this line

```
NSMutableArray *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
```

in this

```
id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
```

And then let the controller do the cast to some Objective-C type as it should know what it is expecting from the service call (the service object is an abstraction, so it hasn't to know what it is handling).
Anyway you're handling a network operation that could fail for network problems or on server side. Controller has to know when it fails as well.

Try also to use `blocks` instead of `protocols` in this case... I see it might be more reusable and it will prevent you to write always a lot of code to allow delegation pattern.
Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html or see the `AFNetworking` code on GitHub, it is completely made with blocks and you can see how to use them

**ADDING**

For me it depends all on OOP. As I'm building an abstract object that will only handle network connections without knowing what it is doing, well, there isn't a reason to keep a reference to the sender (delegate). It should only handle the service and then call an internal endpoint (the block).
You can use a `weak` reference to `self` into the block to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: ok but some services Top level object is " Dictionary" and some services top level object is "Array" in this situation how to handle how to send my response object to my main class

Comment: This has to be declared into the API. You can't receive from the same call different types of JSON (or yes, if there is an error, but you have also to receive some HTTP response code not equal to 200)

Comment: is there any problem using protocols instead of blocks?

Comment: There isn't of course, all the ways to do something are correct! But you must declare into the protocol also a method to handle an error and then implement it in all the object conforming to the protocol

Comment: can u edit my code that how to maintains blocks instead of protocols please

Comment: what about this line(-(void)MainService :(NSMutableArray*) mainArrayList) can keep like that or need to do like (-(void)MainService :(id) mainArrayList) please giev ur suggestion about thsi

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html or see the `AFNetworking` code on GitHub, it is completely made with blocks and you can see how to use them

Comment: Blocks are not generally preferable. They make it harder to cancel asynchronous tasks and often lead to retain cycles. Delegates are great for many things.

Comment: @orkoden It depends on how you use it. Also delegates allow retain cycles if you declare the delegate property as retain/strong. What you're saying isn't correct as you have to build something good. If someone writes code as a newbie, it will be hard to cancel a request or avoid a retain cycles also with the delegates

Comment: @LucaD `NSURLSessionTask ` uses blocks anyway, so you're not really helping a newbie.

Comment: @orkoden I'm not saying that the author of the post is a newbie, I'm sorry if you misunderstood what I wrote.

Comment: @orkoden I added some explanation in the post

Comment: @LucaD The OP's problem has nothing to with protocols or blocks at all anyway.

Comment: Well, I think it depends on the single person. As Apple deprecated NSURLConnection that was using delegates in favor of NSURLSessionTask that uses blocks, it means that it is not so hard to debug. That's what I think, but anyway the solution to the question was the wrong cast.

Comment: Hi @LucaD i am calling "Get" method service and more ever i know here top level object is "Array" then what's is problem if i keep NSMutableArray instead of "id" as u said above can u explain please

Answer (score 1):

Just because JSONSerialization parsed something doesn't mean the result is a dictionary. It could be an array as well. Which would cause the problems you see. And there are no protocols in sight here anywhere. Get an Objective-C book and learn what a protocol is.

And you really need some serious error checking in your code. NSLog isn't error handling. NSLog is for *you* to find problems during development, but you are not handling them.

Personally, if I see things like "BacGroundGetMethodServiceClass", "getServieCalling" I think you need to spend some time making your code more readable. Read some sample application code, and read about Apple's naming guidelines. Methods and variables should be named so the reader can figure out what they are there for without relying on any comments - of which I didn't see any in your code.

Comment: so what is main problem in my code jsonSerialization is main cause? what should i do for resolve my issue help me i am very new for this technology

Comment: @gnasher729 honestly there is the `protocol`, only some pieces of code are missing I think (see `GetCallService` method

Comment: i am not understand what code is missing some times response coming and only some rare cases this exeption is coming

Comment: Look at the JSON data that you are getting and what it contains. You must check what is actually in your JSON data EVERY TIME you get anything, or you will have random crashes forever.

Comment: If your code crashes "in only some rare case" then clearly there is code missing to handle the situation.

Comment: @gnasher ur right and LucaD saying that there is wrong caste please see his above post and tell ur opinion about this

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when parsing the JSON. You can't expect it to be a `NSMutableArray`. It's better to check if it's an `NSArray`.

```
    NSObject *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
    if (!parseError && [responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
```

You can create a `NSMutableArray` from that.

```
[responseObject mutableCopy];
```

The second problem you have, which actually causes the crash, is that you need to be sure the array actually contains dictionaries. You also can't add `nil` to an array, so check that too.

```
  for (NSObject *obj in mainArrayList) {
      if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) obj;
        NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
        if (name) {
            [NameArray addObject:name];
        }
        NSString *identifier = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
        if (identifier){
            [IdArray addObject: identifier];
        }
      }
  }
```

One a more general note: Don't use upper case for method names or instance variables/properties. Upper case is reserved for class names in Objective-C.

Comment: u mean bugs may come if i use upprcase letters?

Comment: No bugs, it's a convention.

Comment: ok in my above post @LucaD saying that that's only cast problem and more ever he has post some code are u agree for his answer @orkoden?

Comment: i just asking ur suggeestion about this topic

Comment: The uppercase letters are not the bugs. But Objective-C has very, very strong coding conventions, and violating the conventions means your code will be buggy, because you cannot find the bugs. And anyone you might ask for help takes one look at the code and walks away.

Comment: @Krish You don't know what type of object `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:]` returns. So you have to check the type and cast to the type checked for. @LucaD's answer explains that, but provides no code for it.

Comment: what code, He has assigned "id" instead of NSMutableArray is it not enough? and if we place "id" instead of NSMutableArray  then the controller do the cast to some Objective-C right?

Comment: You should read up on the basics of Objective-C. Writing `id` instead of `NSMutableArray *` changes nothing about the actual object. It just helps Xcode to autocomplete the correct methods for you, and the compiler to. You don't know what kind of object is returned. Casting doesn't help you without first checking the object's type.

Comment: yes in- spite i keep "id" instead of "NSMUtableArray" now i get again same exception @orkoden ,Can u please explain what is my problem

Comment: so if i have NSDictionary is top Level object instead of NSMutableArray then how can i handle ?

Comment: Look at the contents of the dictionary in the debugger.

Comment: i am very new for this technology that's why i want suggestions of some experts like u to improve my skills

Comment: Just use `NSLog` to output the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99793/discussion-between-krish-and-orkoden).

Answer (score 0):

First of all check error object before calling

```
[self MainService:responseObject];
```

It would be like following lines

```
if (parseError)
   NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData error: %@", parseError);
else
   [self MainService:responseObject];
```

Then while iterating objects of response in `GetCallService` method try following code instead of using NSDictionary

```
for (int i = 0; i < [mainArrayList count]; ++i)
    {
        NSString * Name = [[mainArrayList objectAtIndex:i] obj objectForKey:@"Name"]];
        NSString * Id = [[mainArrayList objectAtIndex:i] obj objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [NameArray addObject:Name];
        [IdArray addObject:Id];
    }
```